# Scala web application security

Tags: security, web-applications, scala

What are good framework choices for web security in a Scala web application. We would like to try out Scala web development, but couldn't yet find good Scala web app security frameworks.

From the Java side I know at least Spring Security and Apache Shiro.

Do you have experience with Scala web app security frameworks or with Spring Security / Apache Shiro in a Scala context?

Answer (score 4):

[Lift](http://liftweb.net/) has security baked in as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683914/why-would-i-use-scala-lift-over-java-spring/3067319#3067319) by David Pollak, the author of Lift.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am also looking for general approaches, which are independent of the web framework

Answer (score 4):

I used Spring Security in small Scala web application. I created it as I started to learn Scala and I tried to use complete Java stack: Spring MVC + Spring + Spring Security + Hibernate + BlazeDS (I also used Flex in this project for the frontend). Now I can tell that it was really nice and positive experience. Generally the question is how good scala integrates with Spring and Hibernate. I had to use `@BeanProperty` or `@BeanInfo` and java collections in entities.

But I have not faced any real issues from the spring security side. It was working as expected. I can remember only one minor issue with Spring AOP: service classes were publishing their methods through BlazeDS to the flex application. I also secured them with Spring Security's object ACLs (with `<security:intercept-methods />` and `<security:protect />`). All this stuff, of course, is possible because of AOP magic. So I noticed this wired Spring AOP's behavior - if your class implements some interfaces, then it will use JDK's proxies to implement them and delegate all calls to target, but if class does not implementing any interfaces, then it will use cglib to extend your class and delegate each method call. The problem is that my public service classes does not implement any interfaces, but AOP was not working properly. The reason is `ScalaObject` interface that is implemented by all scala classes. So I created new traits for all public services in order to solve this problem (I have not found any way to configure Spring AOP - seems that this behavior is hardcoded).

So as you can see it's not a problem to use Spring Security with Scala. I believe that it should be even easier to use Apache Shiro because it claims to be completely container or environment independent (I heard that it's possible to use Spring Security outside Spring, but I also heard that it's pretty painful).  Generally in Scala you can archive everything you can in Java. The question is how pretty/idiomatic/pure/side-effect-free resulting code would be.

By the way, there is a new project that integrates Lift with Apache Shiro: [lift-shiro](https://github.com/timperrett/lift-shiro). [Here](http://blog.getintheloop.eu/2011/08/23/using-apache-shiro-with-lift/) you can also find [small blog post](http://blog.getintheloop.eu/2011/08/23/using-apache-shiro-with-lift/) about it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer. The issue concerning the ScalaObject proxying is really good to know.